# How to check the presence of app in android device?

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk

I'm working on a VoIP SDK. A device may contain more than one app having my SDK. I want to know the **Presence of App A from App B**. Is that possible with or without using any device permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't receive any answer, So I'm giving the easiest solution applied by me.
Use PackageManager to get presense of other app. All you need is **ApplicationID** of that app.

```
    android.content.pm.PackageManager mPm = getPackageManager();  
    PackageInfo info = null;  
    try {
        info = mPm.getPackageInfo("<Put applicationID here>", 0);
        Boolean installed = info != null;
        Log.d("TAG","isInstalled : "+ "" + installed);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("TAG","not Installed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If no application found with respect to applicationId passed, control would go to catch block.